# How to create a solution environment

Tags: environments, conditionals

I want to create a solution environment that works somehow like this:

If at the beginning of the document, solutions are TRUE I want to show the text in the environment and be highlithed.
If it is FALSE, the environment should pretend as if there is no text at all.

Is there any possibility to create such an environment?

Comment: Have a look at ctan.org . There are some packages doing that. Look for package comment and related topics, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of available packages you may choose from.

#### Topic [conditional compilation](https://ctan.org/topic/cond-comp)

Here you see package comment, as I mentioned. However, there may be packages better suited for your unvoiced needs.
[image: condcomp]

#### Package [codesection](https://ctan.org/pkg/codesection)

Does exactly what you described:

[image: codesection]

### Package [multiaudience](https://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience)

It seems to be quite similar:

[image: multiaudience]

#### Package [censor](https://ctan.org/pkg/censor)

As known from film, Muller report and similar documents:

[image: censoring]